# How to add multiple color schemes to Gedit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, color-scheme, gedit

I cloned this git repo and followed instructions but still have to manually browse to the folder and load each color one at a time.

https://github.com/trusktr/gedit-color-schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the shell script to copy the files to ~/.local/share/gedit/styles

```
sudo cp ./*.xml ~/.local/share/gedit/styles/
```

Then make sure permissions are set correctly.

```
cd ~/.local/share/gedit/styles/
```

Replace username and group to yours respectively.

```
sudo chown username:group *
```